# Disallow all pagination pages in robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

I don't want the Google to crawl all my pagination:

Here the are the example:

`http://example.com/blog-page/page/1`

`http://example.com/blog-page/page/2`

`http://example.com/blog-page/page/3`

Well I have some other pagination pages like:

`http://example.com/product-category/product/page/1`

`http://example.com/product-category/product/page/2`

`http://example.com/product-category/product/page/3`

Here are the code for my `robots.txt`

```
User-agent:  *

Disallow: */page/*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent:  *

Disallow: /blog-page/page/
```

You can use this to help you out with robots.txt generating

http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/generator/

Comment: This wouldn't help with the `/product-category/product/page/3` example

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blog-page/page
```

The multiple astricks are not necessary and you have to make sure to include the whole path as `/page` would be the root of your site

Comment: This wouldn't help with the `/product-category/product/page/3` example

Answer (score 0):

There should be no blank line between `User-Agent` and `Disallow`. The trailing `*` is completely unnecessary because `Disallow` rules (including wildcard rules) are all "starts with."

Other than that your `robots.txt` file looks like it will keep search engines out of pagination.  You can test it with [Google's tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en):

[image]

[image]